# Getting QueryString from with a module

Tags: 7

I've trying to get the querystring from within a module.

I've tried the following.  However the following always returns A

exporter/directory?l=o

```
$l = "A";
if ( !empty($_SERVER['l']) ) {
    $l = $_SERVER['l'];
}
```

/* edit */

```
    $l = "A";
if ( !empty($_GET ['l']) ) {
  $l = $_GET ['l'];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query string is stored in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, the same way as when not using Drupal. You can access the individual variables of the query string using the `$_GET` array, the same way as when not using Drupal (with one exception: `$_GET['q']` is the canonical Drupal path, not the one assigned using the Path module).

Comment: thanks just changed above. Is there any reason the $_GET shouldn't work above? This is inside my module page function.

Answer (score 10):

Oswald is correct. Alternatively, in Drupal 7, you can use [drupal_get_query_parameters()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7):

```
$query_parameters = drupal_get_query_parameters();
if (!empty($query_parameters['l'])) {
  $l = $query_parameters['l']
}
```